# How to install the install4j compiler in a scripted way?

Tags: build, scripting, installation, travis-ci, install4j

I contribute to an open source project and would like to use install4j to build installers. I further would like to use Travis-CI as my build server, using their free open-source offer.

Travis runs every build in a fresh VM, and install4j requires a command-line compiler to be present.
Thus, I need to provide/install install4j itself in my build script.

A crude way to go about it would be to fetch an archive from the ej-technologies website every time I build, unzip it and then compile. This requires an OS-switch and a load of archive-handling, depending on the system in use.

I hope there is a better way. How would you go about it?

Comment: Other than unzipping the distribution. I see no other way. Gradle plugin, maven plugin and ant task all require the distribution to be present on the local system and there's currently no way to pull it in through a dependency resolution mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, @IngoKegel. Can you confirm my assumption about the OS-switch, or is one of your downloads maybe OS-independent enough for use in a setup like this?

Comment: install4j does not have platform-independent installers or archives, so the launchers are always OS-specific. The plugins call the command line launcher, so you need the appropriate OS-specific distribution.

Answer (score 1):

[Making @IngoKegel's comments into an answer]
Downloading a fresh copy of Install4J from the ej-technologies website is the only way there currently is. This has to be done separately for each OS, since there are no platform-independent installers or archives.